# EntityFramework Code first 6.1.2 with .Net FX 4.5.3 MaxLengthAttribute Confilict

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

Hello am using the latest EF version 6.1.2 Code first and the latest .Net framework 4.5.3, I really need to use the MaxLength Attribute because i have a unique key (the length must be specified), anyway am getting an error saying that i have a conflict between EntityFramework.dll assembly and System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll assembly because the two contain the MaxLengthAttribute.

is there a way to specify explecitly the MaxLengthAttribute

**NB** 
In **EntityFramework.dll** we have the complete reference of the attribute `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.MaxLengthAttribute`

In **System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll** we have the complete reference of the attribute `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.MaxLengthAttribute`

Comment: Are there not any conflicts with Migration?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fab7a591-f790-4064-aeb5-c320eb5057e5/compilation-error-maxlength-attribute-defined-in-both-entityframework-and-systemdataentity?forum=adodotnetentityframework

Comment: its not migration nor I can remove entityframework from references

Comment: You have referenced the .Net 4.0 EF assembly.

Comment: I had same problem but with EF 6.0.2 and .net 4.5.1. I just uninstalled EF package and installed it again and problem disappeared.